# install lubuntu manual partition mbr no remove option

Tags: lubuntu

Im installing lubunt from usb, I'm following this guide [this](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/1.3/installation.html). But I can't see the option to erase the disk, even executing `sudo swapoff -a`, and it's not clear for me to use PCManFM-Qt, because I don't know what to do.

Anyway, I tried to do a manual partition following some videos but none of them use the 'mbr' disk, so the option's are different, and I don't know how to follow an Ubuntu guide (yes, I tried), because It doesn't have the option 'Install at the beginning'.

Like you see, I don't know a lot about the process of installing Linux distros. So is there any good guide step by step?, Can you explain to me if there's any command that can erase the disk, or to unmount all?

UPDATE:

I only see this options:

- Install alongside
- Replace a partition
- manual partitioning

Comment: Is your goal to install Ubuntu standalone and data in the disk isn't important or is already backed up? If so why don't you select the option to "Erase and install"? Your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Like I said "I can't see the option to erase the disk"

Comment: What options DO you see at that stage?

Comment: It may have helped if you've provided your release details; but your using the Lubuntu 21.10 manual, so I take it you're using the Lubuntu 21.10 release.  Providing a link to a picture of what you do see may also help   (the command `sudo swapoff -a` is executed in a terminal; use Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal, or open via menu, and isn't for `pcmanfm-qt` if that's what you mentioned that for.  Partition checks can be performed in KDE Partition Manager (including unmounts) if helpful.

Comment: Almost all systems will work with gpt. I started converting to gpt in 2010. With old BIOS systems you have to add a bios_grub partition of 1 or 2MB unformatted. I also then converted my 2006 laptop to gpt which is only BIOS boot. UEFI systems use the ESP - efi system partition as FAT32 for UEFI boot files, but unless drive may later be on a newer UEFI system, you do not need the ESP. If drive may be moved often better to add an ESP now. The only place for MBR is for old BIOS only systems and booting Windows in BIOS mode as BIOS Windows only boots from MBR.

Answer (score 0):

Replace a partition - This will erase the partition.

/Edit
To have complete control over your disk, I recommend you install gparted while still using the live usb.

```
ctrl-alt-T
apt-get install gparted
sudo gparted &
```

Here you can delete your partitions, create new partitions and can even format them.

Reboot the live-usb and install.

Comment: It works partially, because it maintains the rest of the partitions, like swap, and I want to remove all.

Comment: -ah.. ok, updated answer.

Comment: KDE Partition Manager is on the disk which does the same thing as `gparted`.

Comment: But, if you read carefully my question, I don't know and I didn't find a way of how to partition a disk with 'mbr' format. That is the reason why I want to erase all, and let lubuntu do whatever needed.

Comment: With either KDE PM or gparted, you can delete all you partitions. Then you can create a new partition table selecting 'msdos' (not GPT). This is what you refer as the old 'mbr' format.

Comment: Again, **you don't want MBR**: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394935/install-lubuntu-manual-partition-mbr-no-remove-option#comment2414258_1394935

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies if:

- You need an MBR partitioned device for some reason
- You want to convert a GPT partitioned device into MBR
- You don't mind **losing all data** in your target device

---

### Steps using the installation setup:

1. Boot from live installation media
2. Select [Install Lubuntu (your version number)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvs4V.png)
3. Choose your location and keyboard distribution
4. Select [Manual partitioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH4MW.png)
5. Select [New Partition Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryT4T.png)
6. And then [MBR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdjnv.png)

This will delete all your current partitions, all data will be deleted when you confirm your choices and start the installation. Double check you've selected the right device in "Storage device:" and "Install boot loader on:".

---

### Using KDE Partition Manager:

- The process is similar, except you will need to right click each existing partition and *Unmount* or *Deactivate swap* before choosing a *New Partition Table*. Data will be deleted only after you press *Apply*.
- Note that, as [Humpity's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394935/install-lubuntu-manual-partition-mbr-no-remove-option/1409560#comment2416110_1395424) points out, MBR is called MS-Dos here.
- Afterwards, follow the same steps as above but skip points 5 and 6. You will then need to modify each partition to have its corresponding mount point (e.g. "/", "Home", ... ).

---

If you can't press *Next*, you probably need to create an ext4 partition mounted as "/boot" in the beginning (I tried with an unformatted one without mount point and it worked, though). 1 GB is the (largest) recommended size in some comments and answers in [this question from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/334665).

Here's an additional MBR and GPT [step by step from linuxbsdos](https://linuxbsdos.com/2015/10/30/gpt-and-mbr-manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-15-10/), although it's for Ubuntu 15.10.